Having problems building android app bundle from kivy.py with buildozer
I'm new at programing. I have never code, but with the IA's help, I want to create an apk from a Python code written with Kivy.
This is my script:
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDockedDatePicker, MDModalInputDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDModalDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import MDSnackbar, MDSnackbarText, MDSnackbarSupportingText
from datetime import timedelta
from functools import partial
from kivy.clock import Clock
from datetime import datetime
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1  # Blanco

    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: dp(20)  # Espaciado entre filas
            padding: dp(20)  # Padding alrededor del contenido

            MDLabel:
                text: "Fecha de inicio y fin:"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

            MDTextField:
                id: field_start_end
                mode: "outlined"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(48)
                on_focus: app.show_modal_date_picker(self)

            MDButton:
                text: "Seleccionar días festivos"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(48)
                on_release: app.show_date_picker(self)

            MDLabel:
                text: "Fechas seleccionadas:"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

            MDTextField:
                id: festivos_seleccionados
                mode: "outlined"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(48)
                readonly: False
                on_text: app.on_festivos_text_changed(self)

            GridLayout:
                cols: 3
                size_hint_y: 1
                height: self.minimum_height

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Selecciona los días de clase y las horas por día:"

            GridLayout:
                cols: 3
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Lunes"

                MDCheckbox:
                    id: checkbox_lunes
                    size_hint_x: 6
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_active: app.toggle_day("lunes", self.active)

                MDTextField:
                    id: horas_lunes
                    mode: "filled"
                    text: "1"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_text: app.update_horas("lunes", self.text)

            GridLayout:
                cols: 3
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(48)

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Martes"

                MDCheckbox:
                    id: checkbox_martes
                    size_hint_x: 6
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_active: app.toggle_day("martes", self.active)

                MDTextField:
                    id: horas_martes
                    mode: "filled"
                    text: "1"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_text: app.update_horas("martes", self.text)

            GridLayout:
                cols: 3
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(48)

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Miércoles"

                MDCheckbox:
                    id: checkbox_miercoles
                    size_hint_x: 6
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_active: app.toggle_day("miercoles", self.active)

                MDTextField:
                    id: horas_miercoles
                    mode: "filled"
                    text: "1"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_text: app.update_horas("miercoles", self.text)

            GridLayout:
                cols: 3
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(48)

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Jueves"

                MDCheckbox:
                    id: checkbox_jueves
                    size_hint_x: 6
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_active: app.toggle_day("jueves", self.active)

                MDTextField:
                    id: horas_jueves
                    mode: "filled"
                    text: "1"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_text: app.update_horas("jueves", self.text)

            GridLayout:
                cols: 3
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(48)

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Viernes"

                MDCheckbox:
                    id: checkbox_viernes
                    size_hint_x: 6
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_active: app.toggle_day("viernes", self.active)

                MDTextField:
                    id: horas_viernes
                    mode: "filled"
                    text: "1"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: dp(48)
                    on_text: app.update_horas("viernes", self.text)

            MDTextField:
                id: counter_label
                text: "Total sesiones: 0"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(100)
'''

class Calculadora(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Olive"
        self.start_date = None
        self.end_date = None
        self.festivos = []

        self.festivos_picker = MDDockedDatePicker(
            on_select_day=self.on_select_festivo
        )

        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        root.ids.festivos_seleccionados.bind(text=lambda instance, value: self.on_festivos_text_changed(instance))

        return root

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dias_seleccionados = {
            "lunes": False,
            "martes": False,
            "miercoles": False,
            "jueves": False,
            "viernes": False,
        }
        self.horas_por_dia = {
        "lunes": 1,
        "martes": 1,
        "miercoles": 1,
        "jueves": 1,
        "viernes": 1,
        "sabado": 1,
        "domingo": 1,
    }

    def update_horas(self, dia, horas):
        try:
            horas_int = int(horas)
            self.horas_por_dia[dia] = horas_int
            self.update_counter()
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def toggle_day(self, checkbox_id, active):
        self.dias_seleccionados[checkbox_id] = active
        self.update_counter()

    def get_weekday_name(self, date):
        weekday_names = {
            0: "lunes",
            1: "martes",
            2: "miercoles",
            3: "jueves",
            4: "viernes",
            5: "sabado",
            6: "domingo"  # Agregar esta línea
        }
        return weekday_names[date.weekday()]

    def update_counter(self):
        if self.start_date and self.end_date:
            dias_seleccionados = [dia for dia, seleccionado in self.dias_seleccionados.items() if seleccionado]

            if not dias_seleccionados:
                self.root.ids.counter_label.text = "Total sesiones: 0"
                return

            filtered_dates = [
                date for date in self.date_range(self.start_date, self.end_date)
                if self.get_weekday_name(date) in dias_seleccionados and date not in self.festivos
            ]
            
            dias_lectivos = sum(self.horas_por_dia[self.get_weekday_name(date)] for date in filtered_dates)

            self.root.ids.counter_label.text = f"Total sesiones:({', '.join(dias_seleccionados)}): {dias_lectivos}"
        else:
            self.root.ids.counter_label.text = "Total sesiones: 0"
                        
    def date_range(self, start_date, end_date):
        # Generar una lista de fechas desde 'start_date' hasta 'end_date'
        return [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)]

    def on_select_month(self, instance_date_picker, number_month):
        # Aquí puedes agregar el código que desees ejecutar cuando se seleccione un mes
        pass
                
    def on_ok(self, instance_date_picker):
        dates = instance_date_picker.get_date()
        if dates:
            self.start_date, self.end_date = dates
            self.root.ids.field_start_end.text = f"{self.start_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} - {self.end_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}"
            self.update_counter()
            
    def on_select_start_end_date(self, instance, value):
        pass

    def on_edit(self, instance_date_picker):
        instance_date_picker.dismiss()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.show_date_picker, 0.2)

    def show_date_picker(self, instance):  # Elimina los argumentos focus y date_type
        def on_edit(*args):
            self.festivos_picker.dismiss()
            Clock.schedule_once(self.show_date_picker, 0.2)

        self.festivos_picker.bind(on_edit=on_edit)
        self.festivos_picker.bind(on_select_day=self.on_select_day)
        self.festivos_picker.bind(on_select_year=self.on_select_year)
        self.festivos_picker.bind(on_select_month=self.on_select_month)
        self.festivos_picker.bind(on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
        self.festivos_picker.bind(on_ok=partial(self.on_ok_festivo, value=None))
        self.festivos_picker.open()

    def on_ok_festivo(self, instance_date_picker, value):
        date_selected = instance_date_picker.get_date()
        if date_selected:
            self.festivos.append(date_selected[0])
            self.update_festivos_text()
            self.update_counter()

        instance_date_picker.bind(on_ok=self.on_ok)
        instance_date_picker.bind(on_select_month=self.on_select_month)

        def on_edit(*args):
            instance_date_picker.dismiss()
            Clock.schedule_once(self.show_modal_date_picker, 0.2)

                
    def on_select_festivo(self, instance, date):
        if date in self.festivos:
            self.festivos.remove(date)
        else:
            if date not in self.festivos:
                self.festivos.append(date)
        self.update_festivos_text()
        self.update_counter()

    def on_festivos_text_changed(self, instance):
        value = instance.text
        fechas_validas = []

        # Iterar sobre las fechas en el campo de texto
        for fecha_str in value.split(","):
            fecha_str = fecha_str.strip()
            if fecha_str:
                try:
                    fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    fechas_validas.append(fecha)
                except ValueError:
                    # Ignorar fechas con formato incorrecto
                    pass

        # Actualizar la lista self.festivos con las fechas válidas
        self.festivos = fechas_validas

        # Actualizar el contador de días lectivos
        self.update_counter()

    def update_festivos_text(self):
        self.root.ids.festivos_seleccionados.text = ", ".join(str(date) for date in self.festivos)

    def on_select_day(self, instance_date_picker, number_day):
        date_selected = instance_date_picker.get_date()[0]
        self.festivos.append(date_selected)
        self.update_counter()
        self.root.ids.festivos_seleccionados.text = ", ".join(str(date) for date in self.festivos)

    def on_select_year(self, instance_date_picker, number_year):
        # Implementa aquí el código que desees ejecutar cuando se seleccione un año
        pass

    def on_cancel(self, instance_date_picker):
        # Implementa aquí el código que desees ejecutar cuando se cancele la selección de fecha
        instance_date_picker.dismiss()

    def on_edit_start_end(self, instance_date_picker):
        instance_date_picker.dismiss()

    def show_modal_date_picker(self, focus):
        if not focus:
            return

        modal_date_picker = MDModalInputDatePicker(mode="range")
        modal_date_picker.bind(on_success=self.on_select_start_end_date)
        modal_date_picker.bind(on_ok=self.on_ok)
        modal_date_picker.bind(on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
        modal_date_picker.open()

Calculadora().run()

The code runs perfectly with 'briefcase dev'
When I tried to build the android aab file o got stucked.
I've tried 'briefcase' and 'buildozer'. And I have achieve nothing.
In my last attempt I've got this error:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
# Command failed: ['/Users/mario/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager', '--sdk_root=/Users/mario/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk', 'platform-tools']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     __CFBundleIdentifier = 'com.apple.Terminal'
#     TMPDIR = '/var/folders/9n/cy3cympn6dx_5x9lvs5bw30w0000gn/T/'
#     XPC_FLAGS = '0x0'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.2RsjG5Aghf/Listeners'
#     XPC_SERVICE_NAME = '0'
#     TERM_PROGRAM = 'Apple_Terminal'
#     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '453'
#     TERM_SESSION_ID = '9CEBEB5D-E86D-4374-8A0E-CA1E708DE3D4'
#     SHELL = '/bin/zsh'
#     HOME = '/Users/mario'
#     LOGNAME = 'mario'
#     USER = 'mario'
#     PATH = '/Users/mario/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/Users/mario/Calculadora/venv/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/mario/.cargo/bin:/Users/mario/Documents/Python/Proyecto/Calculadora/dist'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PWD = '/Users/mario/Calculadora'
#     OLDPWD = '/Users/mario'
#     HOMEBREW_PREFIX = '/opt/homebrew'
#     HOMEBREW_CELLAR = '/opt/homebrew/Cellar'
#     HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY = '/opt/homebrew'
#     MANPATH = '/opt/homebrew/share/man::'
#     INFOPATH = '/opt/homebrew/share/info:'
#     OPENAI_API_KEY = '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'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/Users/mario/Calculadora/venv'
#     PS1 = '(venv) %n@%m %1~ %# '
#     LANG = 'es_ES.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/Users/mario/Calculadora/venv/bin/buildozer'
#     __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F5:0x0:0x8'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

I've tried to erease everything and re-install it again.
I've tried the same process in Windows.
With virtual enviroments and without...

Firstly, ensure to test your app on Windows to ensure smooth operation without errors. Then, explore using Buildozer as your build tool, referring to its documentation for guidance. Begin by creating a simple app with a GUI if you're focusing solely on Android testing, as attempting without it might lead to numerous errors that could be overwhelming.
